# apex:SelectCheckboxes not passing select values to controlller

Tags: apex

When I select checkbox values from the visual force page, they are not received in the controller. Here is the code: 

VF Page

----------------------------------------------------------------

```
<apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!users}" layout="pageDirection" onclick="changePanel('{!$Component.AllPermissions.Panel}',this)">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!userOptions}"/>
</apex:selectCheckboxes>
<apex:actionFunction name="UpdateUser" action="{!checkSelectList}" reRender="" immediate="true"/>
```

Apex Controller:

---------------------------------------------------------------

```
public PageReference checkSelectList()
{
    List<String> con=getUsers();
    System.debug('Selected User------------------------------------------'+con+'--------Selection1 Before----------'+Selection1);
    Selection1='00524000000dT65AAE';    //users[0];
    System.debug('Selected User------------------------------------------'+con+'--------Selection1 After----------'+Selection1);
    return null;
}
```

The "con" returns null. How do I access the selected values?

Comment: Using `immediate=true` prevents the data from the page being posted to the controller. Is the behavior of the checkboxes correct when you remove this attribute?

Comment: If I remove immediate="true". The action function is not invoked at all from the js!

Answer (score 1):

The possible reason for this behaviour can be

1. Areas of the page are being rerendered, but not a page messages
   component, and an required field is missing or a validation rule is
   failing. In this scenario the error will be swallowed and the page
   will remain unchanged.
2. The form submission is using an action region, which excludes the
   input from the server side processing.
3. The form submission component (e.g. commandbutton, actionfunction)
   has the immediate attribute set to true. This will bypass validation
   rules but also discard any input from the user.

You can refer this question in SFSE.

In your case, the actionFuction which calls the method is having immediate="true" which discards the checkboxes selected by the user.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I remove immediate="true". The action function is not invoked at all from the js!

Answer (score 1):

I tried with your code. Though I couldn't find a solution but found some interesting things as below. I hope my findings are helpful for you.

**(1)**

I found that when using `immediate=true` with `<apex:actionFunction`, we must assign values to the apex function via `apex:param`,(thanks to [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000977HIAQ)) like this :

```
<apex:selectRadio id="choose12_InsuredOwner" value="{!PolicyOwnershipStatementInsuredOwner.selected12a}" onclick="checkMandatory(this.value);">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="true" itemLabel="Yes"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="false" itemLabel="No"/>
</apex:selectRadio>

<apex:actionFunction name="checkMandatory" action="{!CheckMandatorySection12}" immediate="true" rerender="main" status="status001">
    <apex:param value="" name="param1" assignTo="{!PolicyOwnershipStatementInsured.selected12a}" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

**(2)**

Well I assigned the value to the `<apex:actionFunction` and again I found this error

**Invalid conversion from runtime type String to `List<String>`
Error is in expression `'{!users}'` in page `checklistcheckpage`**

Again on googling I found [this SFSE link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/9301/edit) that Actually you can't send a list using **actionfunction**.
To pass a list to controller you can consider using **Remoting**(Stateless).

If you want to send a list of Ids you can always send a csv formatted string using js
Something like

```
<script>
    UpdateSelected('a1we00000004EXAAA2,a1we00000004EXBAA2');
</script>
<apex:actionfunction name="UpdateSelected" action="{!TestAction}" rerender="r"> 
    <apex:param name="ids" value="" assignTo="{!SelectedIds}" /> 
</apex:actionfunction>
```

and in the controller method you can split the string into list by

**Example :**

```
public String SelectedIds{get;set;}
public void TestAction(){
 List<String> allIds = SelectedIds.split(',');
}
```

I tried with this modified version of your code.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="cheklistchek">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!users}" layout="pageDirection" onclick="UpdateUser(this.value);">
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!userOptions}"/>
        </apex:selectCheckboxes>
        <apex:actionFunction name="UpdateUser" action="{!checkSelectList}" reRender="" immediate="true">
            <apex:param value="" name="param1" assignTo="{!users}" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**
**public with sharing class cheklistchek {
    public cheklistchek() {

```
}
public List<String> users{get; set;}
//getOptions for userClick Method
public List<SelectOption> getUserOptions(){
    List<SelectOption> useroptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    useroptions.add(new SelectOption('','--select--'));
    useroptions.add(new SelectOption('1','User1'));
    useroptions.add(new SelectOption('2','User2'));
    useroptions.add(new SelectOption('3','User3'));
    useroptions.add(new SelectOption('4','User4'));
    return useroptions;
}   
public PageReference checkSelectList(){
    List<String> con = getUsers();
    System.debug('Selected User'+con);
    //System.debug('Selected User------------------------------------------'+con+'--------Selection1 Before----------'+Selection1);
    //Selection1='00524000000dT65AAE';    //users[0];
    //System.debug('Selected User------------------------------------------'+con+'--------Selection1 After----------'+Selection1);
    return null;
}
public List<String> getUsers() {
    return users;
}
public void setUsers(List<String> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
```

}**

Comment: That is exactly what I found later too Saroj but what is confusing me is that when we were calling ActionFunction. We were not sending the String list of selected checkboxes in the actionFunction. The actionFunction was just calling a controller method that was referencing the variable that was assigned to the select checkboxes component.